# interactively query SQL databases with Linq? Other than Linqpad

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Is there any other utility software available other than [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to interactively query SQL databases and other data sources??
esp linq to entities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linqpad to query a database with EntityFramework

[Linq pad with EF](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx)

Comment: yes we can use but i want to know other than that as I had some trouble with EF queries which were executing in code but not in linq pad

Comment: more over its auto complete version is paid :(

Comment: If your having trouble with EF queries you can use SQl Profiler to see what SQL is being run. I know autocomplete is paid but it is good value.